# Parallel For Each get in a DeadLock

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

i'm trying to loop over a datatable with more then 100 000 row using the Parrallel For each. Everything work fine up to around 25 000 iterations. I dont get any error, and I see the apps still working, but it kind of block and nothing happen. I tried to encapsulate the loop in a factory.startnew and I get a random abort expection at around 5000 iterations for no reason.

```
Dim lstExceptions As New ConcurrentQueue(Of Exception)
Dim options As New ParallelOptions
options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3

Parallel.ForEach(ReservationReportDS.Tables(0).AsEnumerable(), options,
    Sub(row)
        Try
            Dim tmpRow As DataRow = CType(row, DataRow)
            Dim ReservationID As Integer = tmpRow.Field(Of Integer?)("autNoReservation")
            Dim customerID As Integer = tmpRow.Field(Of Integer?)("CustomerID")
            Dim VehiculeID As Integer = tmpRow.Field(Of Integer?)("autNoVehicule")

            Dim bill As New BillingPath()
            bill.Calculate_Billing(ReservationID, customerID, VehiculeID)

        Catch err As Exception
            lstExceptions.Enqueue(err)
        End Try
    End Sub
)

If (lstExceptions.Count > 0) Then
    Throw New AggregateException(lstExceptions)
End If

Catch errAgg As AggregateException
    For Each ex As Exception In errAgg.InnerExceptions
        Log(Log_Billing_UI, "", System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name & GetExceptionInfo(ex))
    Next
Catch ex As Exception
    Log(Log_Billing_UI, "", System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name & GetExceptionInfo(ex))
End Try
```

Comment: Could you add the error stacktrace

Comment: 1) Does `bill.Calculate_Billing` write to the DataSet? 2) A database is designed, with much care and research, to work for that sort of thing, so it might be a good alternative. Also, the data in a database is persistent.

Comment: There is no error, it juste simply block. Using the same data without thread work fine. 

1) Yes Calculate_Billing will do 1 insert 95% of the time, 5% 2 or 3. But the call make many select (at least 10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have such amount of records, I would like to recommend you to think about following concept:

1. Read **all** records into ConcurrentQueue(Of SomeBillingInfoClass) collection first - it will allow you to not keep connection to DB opened, make thread-safe rest operations with data readed from DB.
2. Create list of Tasks with Billing calc code inside. This will allow you to run tasks in parallel and pass ConcurrentQueue variable from #1 easily.
3. Keep tasks running in loop while at least one element in ConcurrentQueue remains.
4. In case you can aggregate billing calculation result to some other class - you may do it using additional thread safe ConcurrentQueue(Of BillingCalcResultInfoClass) collection.
5. After all billings are calculated - write to DB in single thread and single long transaction - this may be faster then granular writing to db.

Some notes about your code - I think you may not need to throw AggregateException manually - .Net environment will do it for you automatically. You only will need to catch it in .ContinueWith() method of task (sorry, mostly I'm c# developer and use c# notation).

I used similar approach to process millions of records and it works fine. Typically I use 3-5 tasks. But you can always study how much tasks you may have.

Using ConcurrentQueue or similar thread safe collection will allow you to keep your code thread safe more easily.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I tried using a List of Tasks, and it look like working for now. For each entry, I'm creating one task for now which full the cpu usage to 100%. Il try to create an algorimth only with a few tasks and see if it work

Comment: @Max_Thom, yes. You can load all records in some thread-safe collection. Run several tasks then and inside each task call collection.TryDequeue method to pop next record. And those tasks should run inside limitless loop which will breaks only if in collection there are no records. This way you can work with only several tasks at the same time and not have 100% CPU usage.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers and especially Anton Norko. I finally found the problem and it was on my side. Under certain condition, Calculate_Billing was stuck in an infinite loop. Since I used 3 threads at the same time, they were getting stuck one by one.